# How can you tell the distribution of variable given a rate?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Say that once somebody contracts a disease, they become infectious at a rate $\lambda$ . Once infectious, the individual will then recover at rate $\lambda$ , independent if how long it took for them to become infectious. Say $Y$ is the total amount of time an individual has the disease. How can you determine $Y$'s distribution given only the above information?

Comment: You already told us that $Y$ is exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you say, it seems that the length of time $Y$ a person has the disease is the sum of two
independent random variables, each of them distributed $\mathsf{Exp}(rate=\lambda).$ Thus, $Y \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(shape=2, rate=\lambda).$ The proof via moment generating functions is simple.

*Notes and references:*

If the two rates are not equal, then the sum has a right-skewed
distribution that is *not* gamma: for details and derivation see, for example, Bibinger: `http://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.3945.pdf`.

The *difference* between two exponential distributions with the same
rate has a Laplace distribution: see the Wikipedia article on 'Laplace
distribution' for a discussion.